# hashtag that support emoji?

Tags: regex, hashtag

I'm trying to find all the hash tags in a string.
They could be anywhere in the text like:

this is a #awesome event, lets use the tag #fun # #中文 #อักษรไทย #မြန်မာဘာသာ #777

Support not only a-z, 1-9 but also Chinese、Thai、Burmese etc

hashtag begin with #, end with kind of @$%^&* space。

How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```php
#[^\s@$%^&*]+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/FWD1yD/2)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\s@$%^&*]+             any character except: whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '@', '$', '%', '^', '&',
                           '*' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```